# Number of ways you sit next to your friend with 4 other people at a round table

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

This is a question I have after seeing Q1 of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958923/what-is-the-probablity-of-sitting-next-to-my-friend). There are a total of 6 people including you and your friend, and you guys are about to sit at a round table. The method of counting the number of sitting positions makes sense to me in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2958934/399379), i.e.

> First there are 6 ways for you to take a seat, 2 ways for your friend to sit next to you. Now with 4 people left with 4 chairs, there are 4!=24 ways for them to sit.

So the total number of ways is 6 * 2 * 4! = 288

However, I have another idea of counting: take my friend and myself as a bundle, and view it's arranging 5 elements (5! ways), my friend and I can switch (2 ways), so there's a total of 5! * 2 = 240.

Why is the difference? Both methods make sense to me.

Just in case there are people not clear about the setup, all 6! (= 720) permutations of the seating arrangements are considered as distinct.

Comment: If label you as "A", your friend as "B", and the remaining four people as "C, D, E, F" respectively.  In your counting, "ABCDEF" and "EFABCD" are different permutations, but they are the same in a round table permutation.

Comment: This question is ambiguous, because "number of ways" can reasonably be interpreted in several ways.  For instance, from my perspective my friend might be next to me, two seats over, or directly opposite me: that's just three possibilities.  At the other extreme, we might consider all $6!=720$ permutations of the seating arrangements to be distinct because we might care where we sit at this table and about who intervenes on either side between myself and my friend.  There are many other possibilities, too.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Why not?  It comes down to what sets of "ways" one considers equivalent and what one considers "next to me" to mean.  Sure, it's natural to interpret that as "adjacent:" but even then the question is ambiguous.  When the actual chairs don't matter and only the relative position does, the answer is two.  When even which side (left or right) doesn't matter, the answer is one.  For each of those answers, would a permutation of the other four seated people count as a distinct new way or not??

Comment: @whuber I don't think "adjacent" is ambiguous, but if the chairs in the table are distinguishable is ambiguous. It looks like the OP treats chairs to be distinguishable, because the total number of indistinguishable-chairs [**circular permutations**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularPermutation.html) is $(6 - 1)! = 120$, how could the answer be more than $120$? Therefore, as a combinatorics problem, I agree with you, it is ambiguous.  On the other hand, if it is a classical probability problem (say, "what is the probability that my friend sits next to me?"), then it is unambiguous.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I am unwilling to parse the text of the question to guess what the OP means, because by offering two contradictory approaches they demonstrate an insufficiently clear formulation of the problem.  I don't understand your remark about "adjacent:" I used that word to *resolve* part of the possible ambiguity in the problem statement, attempting to clarify the meaning of "next to."  Imagine, if you will, a conference room full of tables where "seated next to" a friend means "seated at the same table with a friend."  That's not an unusual meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea also works, but you did a mistake: there are actually 6 ways to sit your bundle of (you + your friend) around the table. See the image: it's actually all 6 sides of a hexagon.

Once you've chosen where to sit the bundle, then you can sit the other people, which is 4!, and you can also switch with your friend, which accounts to 2, as you say.

[image: One of the 6 ways to choose where the bundle is placed.]